# Specifying file path in Mac

Tags: macos, path, identification

I shifted to Mac last week and trying to run python code that i used in my windows machine.  However, I could not specify the file path correctly and repeatedly getting error.

File path as seen from machine:

[image]

The code i used is as follows:

```
 for line in open('Macintosh HD/Users/mageshpoondi/Documents/2015/Travel/IPL2015-5.5.2015.txt')
```

I tried including Magesh's MacBook Pro before Macintosh HD, replaced forward slash with backward ones, removed the space between Macintosh & HD...nothing seem to work...getting an error..."No such file or directory".

I am sure this is a trivial question....but fighting for an answer for couple of hours is frustrating.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want is `/Users/mageshpoondi/Documents/2015/Travel/IPL2015-5.5.2015.txt`.  It's a standard UNIX path.

Comment: That, or `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/`... All mounted volumes live in /Volumes.